# A Code Formatter in VSCode for both C# and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-code

I'm coding C# - ASP.NET Core as Backend and JavaScript - React as Frontend at the same time in VSCode in one 'VSCode window' as two workspaces, if I need to format my JS codes I use 'Prettier' extention and for formatting C# I use 'CSharpier', so I have to change 'fomatter setting' in VSCode between CSharpier and Prettier all the time, is there any extention or anyway to format both languages codes without changing 'formatter setting' in VSCode? or any better idea for coding in both languages at the same time?

VSCode version: 1.85

[image]